# Meaning of "purchase" in context

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Scientists have no special **purchase** on moral or ethical decisions; a climate scientist is no more qualified to comment on health care reform than a physicist is to judge the causes of bee colony collapse.

What's the meaning of **purchase**? Is this usage common or rare?

Comment: It's ***purchase*** in the sense of ***grip, hold*** - loosely, ***claim, right** [to own]*. See [How did 'purchase' evolve to mean 'firm contact or grip'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239317/how-did-purchase-evolve-to-mean-firm-contact-or-grip) over on ELU for a bit more background. It's an "unusual, stylised" metaphoric usage as cited (most people would use ***authority*** or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word "purchase" most commonly means to buy, to exchange money to get something. Like, "I purchased a new lawn mower for $200 yesterday." But it can also mean a "hold or position". See, for example, https://www.thefreedictionary.com/purchase, noun definition 2. Like you might say, "The mountain climber got a firm purchase on the rock and then pulled himself up."

Your example is using "purchase" in this sense, but not literally. Of course you can't literally grab hold of a moral position, but you certain can figuratively grab hold of a moral position.

This definition of "purchase" is relatively rare. If you asked a fluent English speaker to define the word they might not even think of that. But it is an established definition.

Answer (score 2):

It probably means the scientists do not have the *rights* to make moral or ethical decisions (not their job), and this usage of the word "purchase" is quite rare, one that you do not see often.

Comment: I have to disagree with this a bit.  What's your basis for saying it means that?  To me, it looks like the sentence is probably saying scientists don't have any special *right* to make these decisions, not that they *don't*.